# QBO3 Matrix "All" values

Tags: fuzzy-logic, qbo3

I have a QBO3 Matrix with a single Investor input, and a bunch of outputs:

```
| Investor | Output1 | Output2 | Output3 |
| -------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 1,2,3    | A       | B       | C       |
| 4,5      | D       | E       | F       |
| 6,7,8    | D       | B       | G       |
...
```

We now want to add a new "LoanType" input.

- Is there a way to have the investor Code field count for ‘ALL’?
- If I leave the field blank and select ‘Do Not Match’  will that apply to anything but NULL in that field?
- Is there a way to only account for the Investors already listed in the Matrix without having to list them all in the Investor Code field?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR; use input weights to get your desired result.**

Assuming you added a LoanType input with the following rows:

```
| Investor | LoanType | Output1 | Output2 | Output3 |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 1,2,3    |          | A       | B       | C       | row 1
| 4,5      |          | D       | E       | F       | row 2
| 6,7,8    |          | D       | B       | G       | row 3
|          | Jumbo    | H       | I       | F       | row 4
...
```

> Is there a way to have the Investor field count for 'ALL'?

Yes. Row 4 has **no Investor specified**, so all Jumbo loans would consider row 4 a possible match, regardless of investor.

> If I leave the field blank and select ‘Do Not Match’  will that apply
>   to anything but NULL in that field?

Yes, but this is **not recommended**. If you do this, it will match a NULL investor, and it will match any "valid" investor value. This is equivalent to simply not entering anything at all.

> Is there a way to only account for the Investors already listed in the
>   Matrix without having to list them all in the Investor Code field?

Yes, using **weights**.

I'm inferring from your question that if you have:

- Investor = 27 (where Investor 27 does not appear in any other rows in the Matrix)
- LoanType = "Jumbo"

you want row 4, but if you have:

- Investor = 8 (where Investor 8 appears in another row in the Matrix), and
- LoanType = "Jumbo"

you want to match row 3.

If this assumption is correct, you just need to set the Investor input weight to be higher than the LoanType weight. For example:

- Investor.Weight = 10
- LoanType.Weight = 5

In this scenario, given the inputs Investor = 8 and LoanType = "Jumbo", you would have:

```
| Investor | LoanType | Output1 | Output2 | Output3 | Weight |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------ |
| 6,7,8    |          | D       | B       | G       | 10     |
|          | Jumbo    | H       | I       | F       | 5      |
| 1,2,3    |          | A       | B       | C       | 0      |
| 4,5      |          | D       | E       | F       | 0      |
...
```

Thus, your Investor match outweighs your LoanType match.

Lastly, if you had a rare use case where Investor = 2 and LoanType = "Jumbo" should result in Jumbo results, you can just add a row for that use case:

```
| Investor | LoanType | Output1 | Output2 | Output3 |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 1,2,3    |          | A       | B       | C       | row 1
| 4,5      |          | D       | E       | F       | row 2
| 6,7,8    |          | D       | B       | G       | row 3
|          | Jumbo    | H       | I       | F       | row 4
| 2        | Jumbo    | H       | I       | F       | row 5
...
```